# calling service in spring container remotely by play application

Tags: playframework

I am developing a Play application that takes services from a different spring based application. The problem is that the both applications are deployed on different servers. I need to access the spring container of the spring application in my play or any thing by which I can access the beans. I don't know what to do or whether it is possible.

I googled a lot but didn't find any solution.
Somewhere it is suggested to use rest layer. I don't know rest and whether this is exactly the solution/approach I should follow.

Any suggestion will help me lot...

Thanks

Comment: Question: Is your spring service exposed through an API? If yes, then check this out http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/JavaWS , you will have to make HTTP calls to communicate with your service.

Comment: Thanks PGriffin, thats what I was looking for